# Trigger an event when the end +1 of a bootstrap tabs is reached

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code that implements a next and previous buttons for a bootstrap tabs that contains some forms.

When the user navigates to the last tab through the next button, the button(next) text changes to "Submit". Now I want that when the user clicks this supposedly new button (Submit button), I will then submit the form.

At the moment this is my code and it works, but I'm thinking it could be improved, so that I don't have to bind another click event to the submit button again as I currently did.

```
    $('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    if($('.active').not('li:last')){
        $('#next').text('Next');
    }

});

$('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    if($('.active').is('li:last')){
        $(this).text('Submit');

        $(this).click(function() {
            alert('Submitting to server');
        });
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_1" aria-controls="tab_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_2" aria-controls="tab_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_3" aria-controls="tab_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_4" aria-controls="tab_4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_1">Content 1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2">Content 2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_3">Content 3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_4">Content 4</div>
  </div>

  <a id='prev' href='#' class="btn btn-primary">Prev</a>
  <a id='next' href='#' class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: Wow!! the html is about 1200 lines, And I don't think it is necessary in this case since the selectors will depict the picture. But from the js script you can see how the markup will be like. My code fine, just that  I need improvement.

Comment: Still, an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed.

Comment: @ZimSystem Yes.. I will do exactly that. Thanks.